# UiTextField leftViewMode odd Behavior.. Bug?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `textFields`, in each `textField` I want to put an icon in the `leftImageView`. When I attempt to load this view, the UI gets hung up and never loads. If I comment out one of the tag blocks. My UI loads fine and I end up with a textfield with an icon in the leftView.

My issue is getting an icon in both textFields.

```
    for textField in textFields {
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.autocorrectionType = .No
        textField.leftViewMode = .Always

        if textField.tag == 1 {
            textField.keyboardType = .EmailAddress
            textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedText("Username")

            leftImageViews[0].image = UIImage(named: "user")
            leftImageViews[0].contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            leftTextFieldViews[0].addSubview(leftImageViews[0])
            textField.leftView = leftTextFieldViews[0]
            textField.leftView?.frame = leftTextFieldViews[0].frame

        } else if textField.tag == 2 {
            textField.secureTextEntry = true
            textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedText("Password")

            leftImageViews[1].image = UIImage(named: "password")
            leftImageViews[1].contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            leftTextFieldViews[1].addSubview(leftImageViews[1])
            textField.leftView = leftTextFieldViews[1]
            textField.leftView?.frame = leftTextFieldViews[1].frame

        }
    }
```

Comment: ... why... why don't you just make separate outlets for each text field instead of looping over outlets and having a big `if`-`else` for each *based on **tag***?!

Comment: Are leftImageViews and leftTextFieldViews initialized correctly? Looks like they will need a UIView of some kind. Just checking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @IBOutlet var collectionOftextfields: Array<UITextField>?

 for i in 0 ..< collectionOftextfields!.count {
        let textfieldimage = UIImageView()
        let image = UIImage(named: "xyz.png")
        textfieldimage.image = image
        textfieldimage.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 200,width: 8,height: 8)
        var myField = UITextField()
        myField = collectionOftextfields![i]
        myField.leftView = textfieldimage
        myField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    }
```

Let me know if you need help with how to add textfields to a collection.
Hope this helps.